# Is it possible to debug running SAM start-api instance with Pycharm?

Tags: debugging, aws-lambda, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm community(though if it's only possible with professional then it would be great too) to develop for AWS SAM lambdas. The flow is: Clicking on something the UI that calls the API which will call the AWS lambda function if needed. Is it possible to debug these lambda calls with Pycharm without the need to invoke manually?

I tried to look through AWS toolbox, but that only works for manually invoking lambda functions.